# custom function in office script?

Tags: excel, office-scripts

In Excel VBA I created the below custom function.  Is it possible to replicate that in Excel script?

```
Function ColorSum(myrange As Range, mycolorindex As Integer) As Double
    Dim c As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each c In myrange.Cells
        If c.Interior.ColorIndex = mycolorindex Then _
          ColorSum = ColorSum + c.Value
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: what is `Excel script`? Are you talking formula?  If so, then the answer is no.

Comment: TypeScript for excel.   is there a way to create custom functions in excel online?

Comment: With Office Scripts you cannot achieve this, you will have to use Office JS and creating a custom function is a little more complicated than you think. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can't create custom functions with Office Scripts. To have this feature request considered in our planning process, you can add the request on our [User Voice page](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/274580-excel-for-the-web?category_id=143439).

Thanks - The Office Scripts Team

Comment: I guess the share link is not longer available, instead people can use the link to: [Microsoft Feedback](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/)